# Error: E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory - Android Studio

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, api

I am trying to do a POST Request with volley to interact with a MySQL Database through a local API. I am following a little tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2KKIqrp8Y0) Everything seems to be good but the app send me a timeout error with "E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory" written in red in the Run of Android Studio.

Here some code:

**demovolley/post.php**

```php
<?php
include "dbConnect.php";

$ten = $_POST['TEN'];
$email = $_POST['EMAIL'];

try{
    //print ("Erreur%");
    $conn = dbConnect();
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sinhvien VALUES (null, '$ten','$email')");
    $query->execute();
    /*if($ligne = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        print (json_encode($ligne));
    }*/
}catch(PDOException $e){
    print "Erreur: " .$e->getMessage();
    die();
}

?>
```

This query works I've tested it with Insomnia and the datas were inserted into my table

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.mds.demovolley;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtTen,edtMail;
    Button btnGoi;
    String URL_POST = "https://*my-ip*/demovolley/post.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edtTen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        edtMail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btnGoi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        btnGoi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                InsertSV();
            }
        });
    }

    private void InsertSV(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL_POST, new Response.Listener<String>(){

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String Ten = edtTen.getText().toString();
                String MAIL = edtMail.getText().toString();
                params.put("TEN",Ten);
                params.put("EMAIL",MAIL);

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've read some things on forums but I'haven't found the solution
Could everyone help me?
(PS: Sorry if my english is not pretty good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also face this error that time I closed the project and later on after 2 days when I was started Android studio agian then it won't come again in short it automatically solve by system.